# Getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I am trying to make an application that should help making Dungeon and Dragons items easier for the user!

I have 3 lists of different weapons, with different stats etc. 2 of the lists are added to the program just fine, but 1 of them throws the NoSuchElementException. I really don't understand why, as I can't find anything remotely different from that list, compared to the other lists I've got.

A line from the list looks like this:

```
 Light Melee Weapon,1d4,1d6,x2,10 ft.,Slashing,Axe (Throwing),8 gp, 2lb.
```

http://pastebin.com/Fb2db0f1 link to the entire list causing problems if you want to have a look.

http://pastebin.com/9Hg0Rw2a also link to a list that works just fine!

I hope the method is not too long for you to look through. I've really done all I could think of to try and fix this. And I am positive that it's the list causing a problem, because as soon as I removing it from the destination it reads from, the program runs just fine!

It runs through the for loop just fine on the lists that work, but that first list just won't work ._.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
at MainGUI.init(MainGUI.java:60)
at MainGUI.main(MainGUI.java:32)

public HashMap<String,Weapon> init() {
    String path = "base";
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if(listOfFiles.length == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainGUI.this, "The folder \"base\" was empty"+
                " so no weapons or armor was attempted loaded.", "Warning",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
    HashMap<String, Weapon> weapons = new HashMap<>();
    BufferedReader r = null;
    for(File f : listOfFiles) {
        if(f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            String line;
            try {
                r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    Weapon w;
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                        w = new Weapon(WeaponCategory.fromString(st.nextToken()),
                                st.nextToken(),st.nextToken(),st.nextToken(),
                                st.nextToken(),st.nextToken(),st.nextToken(),
                                st.nextToken(),st.nextToken());
                        weapons.put(w.getName(), w);
                    }
                }
            } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainGUI.this, "The File "+
                    f.getName() + " was not found.", "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainGUI.this, "There was a problem reading "+
                        f.getName() + ".", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        r.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainGUI.this, "An error occured while"
                + "closing the File Reader Stream:\n"+ex.getMessage(),
                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return weapons;
}
```

Comment: Add a System.out.println(line) to identify which line causes the problem. And close every reader, and not just the last one.

Comment: It just stops when it reaches that specific file.

Comment: So what? What prevents you from writing the line to System.out?

Comment: Make your comment into an answer and I will accept it. It didn't really solve my question as a whole, but it got me to the solution myself. There was a typo in a line. Thanks a lot though! :D

Comment: Your list line 13 lacks of one token.

Comment: Yeah I found it. That should have been an answer though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code like this

```
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                    w = new Weapon(WeaponCategory.fromString(st.nextToken()),
                            st.nextToken(),st.nextToken(),st.nextToken(),
                            st.nextToken(),st.nextToken(),st.nextToken(),
                            st.nextToken(),st.nextToken());
                    weapons.put(w.getName(), w);
                }
```

is unsafe as you assume that each input line has 9 items in it. You should check for the number of items and handle invalid lines gracefully (by e.g. writing out the contents of the line to make it easier to identify the problem).

One simple way to achieve this would be to use `String.split()` to tokenize the line. It returns a `String[]` and you can easily check its size before trying to access its elements.

Comment: Yeah, I should. This was a fast prototype thing, so I didn't really do much to it. Appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but it's not really the cause. However it is good to note that I should have done what you suggest there. If you want to know the solution, then please look at the comments of my question.

Comment: @Vipar, Strictly speaking, yes, the root cause was the invalid line in that file. However, a properly written program should handle such cases gracefully, displaying a proper error message which contains all the needed information to find and fix the error in the input file. So in this sense, the cause of your problem was indeed a bug in the code.

Comment: No. The program acted as it was supposed. It didn't have bugs. The thing that had a bug, was the input file. The program didn't have a way to handle this, I agree, but that is not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Stringtokenizer is a bit old school nowadays.

You could use Scanner or just split on commas if you are sure you are not going to have entries that include commas.

If you went with split you could do a check to see if the amount of entries in the parts contains the right number of elements:

```
 String[] parts = line.split(",")
 if (parts.length != 9){
   throw new RuntimeException("Bad line : " + line);
 }
 ...
 //continue processing
```

You could also have a counter that was incremented on each line and then you could display which line causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchElementException occured due to some if the input is exhausted, which is unlikely to happen with standard input (it will block instead). An incorrect value will produce an InputMismatchException.

If there is no any data type check then not to worry. But If you want to have different data type then should check before adding in to bean object.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply ...

```
    String splitString = "Hi! Amazing! wonderful!"
    for (String token : splitString.split("!")) {
        System.out.println(token.toString());
    }
```

- **Result:**

  ```
     Hi!
     Amazing!
     wonderful!
  ```

Comment: Dude, this question was posted in 2012